# WSO2 Api Manager sequence to write to a file is not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

Recently we started looking into WSO2 Api Manager and want to create a fault flow sequence, which will write some information about the fauilure to a file located in file system. The WSO2 API Manager installation is for **Windows**.

I followed the documentation steps from [this dock page](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/VFS+Transport#VFSTransport-URLpa) to enable VFS transport. Then I followed this example [from the docks](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Sample+271:+File+Processing#Sample271:FileProcessing-Introduction) to create a file proxy and file write sequence (I skipped database and file reader as I don't need them):

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="fileWriteSequence">
<log level="custom">
    <property name="sequence" value="fileWriteSequence"/>
</log>
<property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" expression="fn:concat(fn:substring-after(get-property('MessageID'), 'urn:uuid:'), '.txt')" scope="transport"/>
<property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="transport.vfs.Locking" value="disable" scope="transport"/>
<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
<send>
    <endpoint name="FileEpr">
        <address uri="vfs:file:///C:/home/username/test/out"/>
    </endpoint>
</send>
```

I have created API and uploaded sequence just fine and looks like it is being triggered as expected, but the file is not being created - this is the log from the process:

```
[2017-03-10 08:27:02,525]  INFO - LogMediator sequence = fileWriteSequence
[2017-03-10 08:27:03,384] ERROR - VFSUtils Cannot get the lock for the file : file:///C:/home/username/test/out/* before processing
[2017-03-10 08:27:03,385]  WARN - VFSTransportSender Couldn't get the lock for the file : file:///C:/home/username/test/out/*, retry : 1 scheduled after : 30000
```

First I thought it is an issue with permissions, but I granted full controll for anonymous user for this location and run WSO2 AM process as an Administrator - still no luck.

**UPDATE**

I did a workaround by disabling file locking in global configuration (axis2)

```
<transportSender name="vfs" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportSender">
<parameter name="transport.vfs.Locking">disable</parameter>
</transportSender>
```

It still doesn't work, but the error is slightly different (still complains about the path).

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\home\username\test\out\* (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.local.LocalFile.doGetOutputStream(LocalFile.java:251)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getOutputStream(AbstractFileObject.java:1399)
```

As you might notice, there is `"*"` at the end and I am not surprised that whole file path cannot be found, but it is added by the lib, so it is possible that it is expected.

Does anyone have any experience with WSO2 ESB/AM and knows how to solve this? It might be trivial, but after many tries I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: I think you're adress uri is wrong. Try vfs:file://C:/home/username/test/out instead of vfs:file:///C:/home/username/test/out (removed one slash because it's Windows)

Comment: Well, I checked that when I was investigating and it doesn't change anything. In fact the engine adds this slash by itself. I did a workaround for this lock (by disabling), updated my message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I was able to "fix" this, but not fully.

It came out that the `"*"` comes from the endpoint I have created for the API I am accessing in WSO2 API Manager. So once I added new endpoint (resource), example `"/test"`, sequence creates a file "test" under path specified with desired content.
It is still far from ideal, because looks like API Manager just ignores ReplyFileName parameter. Nevertheless, let's say that solved main issue I was facing, so I will start further research from that point.

Answer (score 0):

Your config work for me, take a look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="writeFile"
       transports="http https"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <moc:QRY_SELECT_SRH_PERSONA xmlns:moc="http://www.example.org/mockWS/">
                  <INT_ID xmlns="">1</INT_ID>
               </moc:QRY_SELECT_SRH_PERSONA>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="sequence" value="fileWriteSequence"/>
         </log>
         <property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                   name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"
                   expression="fn:concat(fn:substring-after(get-property('MessageID'), 'urn:uuid:'), '.txt')"
                   scope="transport"/>
         <property name="transport.vfs.Locking" value="disable" scope="transport"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint name="FileEpr">
               <address uri="vfs:file:///C:/home/username/test/out"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="text" value="Error Sequence FAIL"/>
            <property name="message" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
            <property name="code" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
            <property name="detail" expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"/>
            <property name="exception" expression="get-property('ERROR_EXCEPTION')"/>
         </log>
      </faultSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

My file in C:\home\username\test\out\8a11314c-4c22-4ad3-bbfc-4fb56ba415a0.txt
with this content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><moc:QRY_SELECT_SRH_PERSONA xmlns:moc="http://www.example.org/mockWS/"><INT_ID>1</INT_ID></moc:QRY_SELECT_SRH_PERSONA></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

UPDATE 1:

The sequence outside the proxy config:

```
<sequence name="faultSEQ" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <moc:QRY_SELECT_SRH_PERSONA xmlns:moc="http://www.example.org/mockWS/">
                  <INT_ID xmlns="">1</INT_ID>
               </moc:QRY_SELECT_SRH_PERSONA>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="sequence" value="fileWriteSequence"/>
         </log>
         <property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                   name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"
                   expression="fn:concat(fn:substring-after(get-property('MessageID'), 'urn:uuid:'), '.txt')"
                   scope="transport"/>
         <property name="transport.vfs.Locking" value="disable" scope="transport"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint name="FileEpr">
               <address uri="vfs:file:///C:/home/username/test/out"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
</sequence>
```

Comment: So you added this proxy, but have you linked it somehow to the API? I need to write a faulty sequence and link it to specific API (preferably from API Manager UI). And how did you trigger this file creation?

Comment: yes sure, please take a look to this link: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Working+with+Sequences

Comment: ok, but you used WSO ESB - do you know how to create a WSO2 API Manager compatible sequence? WSO2 AM does not operate on proxies, so this solution does not match what I need - sorry if my question was misleading, but I want to integrate this sequence into WSO2 AM, not plain ESB

Comment: If you read my question, I already had the same sequence written, so it doesn't solve anything - on Windows the file is not being created (it cannot create path C:/home/username/test/out/*), and on Ubuntu it crates file called *, but empty. Did this sequence work for you in Api Manager?